# Rails Has Many Through date field of one model falls between dates of other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, rails-admin

**Setup:**
I have a **Job** and a **Price** model where the Job has two fields **start_date** and **end_date** and the **Price** has another date field **effective_at**. The **Job** has_many **Prices** though a region. I'm using the **by_star** gem which allows queries like **between_times** that simply gets the records between the defined fields in the model.

I need all the **Prices** that fall between the Job's **start_date** and **end_date**. I believe I need it to be defined in the **has_many through** due to the rails_admin framework but cannot figure the best way to accomplish it. Here are the models:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :prices, through: :region
  # fields: start_date, end_date
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :jobs, through: :region
  # fields: effective_at
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :prices
end
```

I'm limited in ways to accomplish this due to the fact that the app is built on the **rails_admin** framework, otherwise I would do something like below (which works fine but won't display correctly in the **rails_admin** framework.

```
def job_opis_prices
  prices.between_times(self.start_date, self.end_date)
end
```

I've also tried:

```
class FracJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opis_prices, through: :region do
    def during_job
      where(effective_at: between_times( start_time..end_time ))
    end
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated GREATLY!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `default_scope`, such as

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { joins(:jobs).where('prices.created_at between jobs.created_at and jobs.updated_at') }
end
```